# timer stopped and jump to certain second

Tags: c#

I made a sample project. Where every 10 second it do some function. But when I try to show a timer tick in label it always stuck, and jump to certain second `(eg: stuck at 9s and suddenly jump to 12s)`. What i want to ask,

1. Is my function run properly ?
2. Is my tick, skipped a few ms ? (it will overlap with my function)
3. How do I run it as a thread ?

**My code**

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        timer1.Start();
    }

    int x = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += 1;
        label1.Text = x.ToString();
        if (x % 10 == 0)
        {
            addpoint();
            //MessageBox.Show("success");
        }

    }
```

how to keep my label1.text keep updating, while do addpoint() function

**Note:**

I have set `timer1 interval = 1000`

**update**

i test it with this.

```
public void addpoint()
    {
        string x = @"c:\test\a.txt";
        string text = "haiaiaia";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(x, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Byte[] xx = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            fs.Write(xx, 0, xx.Length);
        }
        Messagebox.show("Created !");
    }
```

Comment: How long does it take you to click away the messagebox?

Comment: What kind of timer? Does the problem exist with the code as shown (with the messagebox commented out) or only if the messagebox is present? Is your program doing other things, either on a timer or in response to clicks, that could block the timer from operating?

Comment: Is the `label1.Text` update needed inside this timer? If not, why not set the timer interval to `10000`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen iam sorry, i forgot to delete the messagebox comment.
well, the thing is whenever i do function `addpoint` my label1.text just jumped to 12s

Comment: what does `addpoint` do and how long does it take for the function to finish?

Comment: @Corak i just want to check the timer per second. after 10s, it run `addpoint` function. but my label1.text is not updating. but when it update, the text was `12s`

Comment: @MongZhu it was a mock program. i don't quite sure. maybe 1-2 second. how do my label keep updating ? when ever i run addpoint function

Comment: it looks like your using a `Windows.Forms.Timer` which is executed on the main thread. The advantage is that you don't need to call `Invoke`, the disadvantage is that `addpoint` is also executed on the main thread and hence blocks your GUI from update, when in the mean time the next tick events are fired

Comment: either run the `addpoint` method on another thread like this: `Thread t = new Thread(()=>addpoint); t.Start()` or use a `System.Timers.Timer` this will be executed on a different thread. But then you will need to invoke the label change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154209/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-chopperfield).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your using a Windows.Forms.Timer which is executed on the main thread. The advantage is that you don't need to call Invoke, the disadvantage is that addpoint is also executed on the main thread and hence blocks your GUI from update, when in the mean time the next tick events are fired.

You can verify it be replacing the call of `addpoint` with `Thread.Sleep(3000)` and you will experience the same behaviour.

What you could do is to try and run the method on another thread:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x += 1;
    label1.Text = x.ToString();
    if (x % 10 == 0)
    {
         Thread t = new Thread(addpoint); 
         t.Start();
    }
}
```

This should avoid the blocking of the GUI.

Disclaimer:

It is important to know what you actually do in `addpoint`, because this solution might lead to race condition and wrong functioning of the method. For example if you are using class variables in it, and if the possibility exists that a second thread can be started while the first has not finished yet! Be aware.

Comment: what if he just create function with async keyword more physible . .

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin yes he could. What does `physible` mean ?

Comment: iam sorry. i tried to put some message box at the of the `addpoint` function. but its not appearing. i think it don't run the function

Comment: Yes actually its feasible  . . .my spelling mistake . .

Comment: @chopperfield I tested my code, it should work. So do you still have the problems with the label?

Comment: @MongZhu nope. it don't run the function.

Comment: @chopperfield so `addpoint` is not executed ?=! how do you test it?

Comment: @MongZhu maybe you can test it with this sample code

Comment: @chopperfield I tried your implementation of `addpoint` and it works perfectly, the file is created, I see the message box and the counting does not skip any numbers in the label. There must be something else. You probably have no rights to write to `C:\test` so `fs.Write` throws an exception

Comment: @chopperfield try to put the call `fs.Write(xx, ..` it in a try/catch block and shoot the stacktrace of the exception into the message box. What does it say?

Comment: @MongZhu i feel ashamed. after i check your code i forget to start the `t` thread. WORK fine dude, !

Comment: @chopperfield don't be. :) It happens also to me from time to time.. spending hours to program a method, and then wondering why it does not work.. until I realize that I also should have called the method that I wrote so  tediously ;) Good fortune

Comment: @MongZhu i have a question. can we use multiple thread whether in one local scope or global ? what does it effecT?

Comment: @MongZhu because surely one day or project need to run some function simultaneously so no need to run it as serial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154210/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-chopperfield).